# HoltWinters model in R

Tags: r, forecasting, trend, holtwinters

We can build HoltWinters model in R using HoltWinters() function, but how to adjust a damped trend? In Holt model (holt() function in R) we can set parameter that our trend can be damped (damped=TRUE). How we can do it in HoltWinters model? Is there any trick for this?

Answer (score 1):

`HoltWinters` and `holt` come from different packages - the first from `stats`, the second from `forecast`.

You can create a Holt Winters model in `forecast` package using `hw` function. The syntax is same as for `holt`, so just set `hw(y, damped = T)` when creating your model.